# Question about definition of upper derivative and lower derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definition

I study the definition of upper and lower derivative in the book Real Analysis H.L. Royden 4th edition.

$\overline{D}f(x)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\left[\sup\limits_{0<|t|\leq h}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}\right]$ is definition of upper derivative

$\underline{D}f(x)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\left[\inf\limits_{0<|t|\leq h}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}\right]$ is definition of lower derivative

For me, this definition feels nonsense because when h is negative $0<|t|\leq h$ part looks undefined. So, I think correct definition of upper derivative is $\overline{D}f(x)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0+}\left[\sup\limits_{0<|t|\leq h}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}\right]$

I think I'm missing very trivial point but I cannot figure out that point myself.

I would appreciate your reply.

Comment: The positiveness of $h$ is implied in $0 < |t| \le h$.

Comment: You don't just have the condition $h \to 0$ over $h$. You have a second condition which is $0<|t|<h$. These two conditions imply $h\to 0^+$.

Comment: Oh I miss that $0<|t|\leq h$ implies $0< h$. Thanks for all replies.